# Ruby: Why does unpack('Q') give a different result than manual conversion?

Tags: ruby, unpack

I'm trying to write a function that will `.unpack('Q')` (unpack to uint64_t) without access to the unpack method.

When I manually convert from string to binary to uint64, I get a different result than `.unpack('Q')`:

```
Integer('abcdefgh'.unpack('B*').first, 2) # => 7017280452245743464

'abcdefgh'.unpack('Q').first # => 7523094288207667809
```

I don't understand what's happening here.

I also don't understand why the output of `.unpack('Q')` is fixed regardless of the size of the input. If I add a thousand characters after 'abcdefgh' and then unpack('Q') it, I still just get `[7523094288207667809]`?

Comment: Because the directive is different. If you do `'abcdefgh'.unpack('C*').pack('c*')` I shall get the same result. But if you convert it to a different bit length characters, you will get different bit variable being stored in your OS. But essentially they are the same.

Comment: Try doing this, `'abcdefgh'.unpack('C*').pack('Q*')`. You will get different result, which is 64 bit.

Comment: I choose `C*` because it returns binary value and not its [string representation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-unpack).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Byte order matters:

```
 Integer('abcdefgh'.
           each_char.
           flat_map { |c| c.unpack('B*') }.
           reverse.
           join, 2)
 #⇒ 7523094288207667809
 'abcdefgh'.unpack('Q*').first
 #⇒ 7523094288207667809
```

Your code produces the wrong result because after converting to binary, [bytes should be reversed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

---

For the last part of your question, the reason the output of `.unpack('Q')` doesn't change with a longer input string is because the format is specifying a single 64-bit value so any characters after the first 8 are ignored. If you specified a format of `Q2` and a 16 character string you'd decode 2 values:

```
> 'abcdefghihjklmno'.unpack('Q2')
=> [7523094288207667809, 8029475498074204265]
```

and again you'd find adding additional characters wouldn't change the result:

```
> 'abcdefghihjklmnofoofoo'.unpack('Q2')
=> [7523094288207667809, 8029475498074204265]
```

A format of `Q*` would return as many values as multiples of 64-bits were in the input:

```
> 'abcdefghihjklmnopqrstuvw'.unpack('Q*')
=> [7523094288207667809, 8029475498074204265, 8608196880778817904]
> 'abcdefghihjklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.unpack('Q*')
=> [7523094288207667809, 8029475498074204265, 8608196880778817904]
```

Comment: This is a great answer! Instead of posting a separate answer I've just added some examples to cover the last part of the question, and replaced `split` with `each_char`, which feels a bit clearer. Hope this is ok.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I tried this, but I think I must have accidentally reversed the bits instead of reversing the bytes.